# Как собирать статистику через php и отбрасывать ботов?

Tags: php

Народ привет!

Интересует именно свой собственный сбор статистики через php, собирает сильно много как мне кажется данных в день до 120 посещение, хотя яндекс показывает 20.

Как я понял ботов много.

**Как эту проблему вообще решить или хотя бы близко подойти к решению?**

Comment: Посмотрите  исходники любого анализатора логов, например. Отпадёт и этот вопрос, и много ещё вопросов, которые могут появиться.

Comment: есть где глянуть их? если не сложно тыкнуть носом =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самая полная статистика берется из логов веб-сервера. Там, в частности, отображаются обращения к статическим файлам, которые РНР не видит.

Ну а чтобы отсеять ботов, самое очевидное решение - смотреть `$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']`.

Как вариант можно яваскриптом дергать файл на сервере, и записывать обращения только в этом файле. Большинство ботов не исполняют яваскрипт, так что статистика должна получиться приближенная к реальности.

Ну а остальные данные для статистики брать из массива `$_SERVER`.

Comment: отличный ответ, еще вопрос: как это узнавать через JS например?

Comment: Что "это" узнавать?